# MemoryInfo.availMem keeps decreasing

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, android-memory

The callback onLowMemory() of my Activity kept on being called and so to investigate the issue, I wrote the following lines of code in the main game loop:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) Activity.getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
Log.v("Tag", "Testing mem: " + mi.availMem);
```

The logs were very interesting: the availMem kept on decreasing. Now to make sure objects were being destroyed properly I I took hprof memory dumps. The objects that were being destroyed, as expected, are not showing in those dumps.

Also, availMem is supposed to be memory available to the whole system and not just my app, which makes it even weirder.

Can anybody help me understand whats going on here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is that actually a problem ? does it reaches 0 ?

Comment: @njzk2 On launch, it was 123314176. It went down to 22675456 and that is when Activity.onLowMemory got called. On 17154048 the app crashed because of low memory.

Comment: Are you doing anything with bitmaps?

Comment: @Simon its a game, there are A LOT of bitmaps

Comment: Are you unbinding the bitmap callbacks and recycling?

Comment: @njzk2 I know I am doing something wrong.. but why dont I see it on hprof memory dumps?

Comment: @Simon other than hprof dumps, is there an alternative to knowing that I am doing all that right?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you don't see the leaks, and, how to show them.  I'll get back if I find a good solution for you.  In the meantime, you might want to search on here for "vm heap budget bitmaps"

Comment: heap dumps will only show you the objects in the Dalvik heap. Bitmap images are kept in the native heap. You won't see the allocations for the actual bitmaps in the Dalvik heap. You can use DDMS or `adb shell dumpsys meminfo` to watch your native heap usage. You can also use `Debug.getMemoryInfo()` in your code to get information about the native heap usage.

Comment: @DavidWasser AFAIK, what you've said holds true for Android 2.2 and less. After 2.2, bitmaps are kept in Dalvik heap ..

Comment: Nope. Starting with 3.0 bitmaps are stored in the Dalvik heap.